# hibernate| find by id for @OneToOne returns entity in recursion

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, one-to-one

I Have two entity class Movie and movie cast with one to one relationship when I save them it is saved properly in DB(Postgres)

but when I do find by Id I get recursive/cascading result meaning:

Movie object is having the movie cast and then further internal movie cast is having
a movie object which further has movie cast (see below  response)

```
"movieName": "The Shawshank Redemption5",
"creationDateTime": "2023-06-29T20:12:07.379",
"updatedDateTime": "2023-06-29T20:12:07.379",
"releaseDate": "1994-01-01",
"releaseYear": 1997,
"type": "DRAMA",
"movieCasts": {
    "castId": 1,
    "movie": {
        "movieName": "The Shawshank Redemption5",
        "creationDateTime": "2023-06-29T20:12:07.379",
        "updatedDateTime": "2023-06-29T20:12:07.379",
        "releaseDate": "1994-01-01",
        "releaseYear": 1997,
        "type": "DRAMA",
        "movieCasts": {
            "castId": 1,
            "movie": {
                "movieName": "The Shawshank Redemption5",
                "creationDateTime": "2023-06-29T20:12:07.379",
                "updatedDateTime": "2023-06-29T20:12:07.379",
                "releaseDate": "1994-01-01",
                "releaseYear": 1997,
                "type": "DRAMA",
                "movieCasts": {
                    "castId": 1,
                    "movie": {
```

...... and so on

My Entity class is :

```
@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Movie {

    @Id
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String movieName;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private LocalDate releaseDate;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Integer releaseYear;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private GENRE type;


    @OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
   @JoinColumn(name="cast_id",referencedColumnName = "castId")
    private MovieCast movieCasts;

}
```

And---------------

```
@Entity
@Data
public class MovieCast {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
  private Long castId;

 // @OneToOne
  @OneToOne(mappedBy = "movieCasts")
  private Movie movie;
  private String director;
  private String producer;
  private  String leadActor;
  private String leadActress;
  private String [] otherActors;
}


@Repository
public class MovieEntityRepo {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;


    public Movie findByName(String name){
        return em.find(Movie.class,name);
    }
}
```

DB snippet after save

```
Movies table
movie_name,creation_date,release_date,release_year,type,updation_date,    **cast_id**
The Shawshank Redemption5,2023-06-29 20:12:07.379,1994-01-01,1997,DRAMA,2023-06-29 20:12:07.379,**1**

Movie_cast

cast_id,director,lead_actor,lead_actress,other_actors,producer
1,director1,leader1,leader2,58 bytes,producer1
```

UPDATING THE Screen shot of actual issue , my issue is not for json but the find method

[image: find method]

Comment: You can either add JsonIgnore (as @chameerar suggested), but a a better solution- that would be suggested by any reviewer -don't mix the responsibilities. JPA entities should not be serialized to a DTO directly. So You need to create a DTO class, map all required fields, then create a JSON from this object. Each class in a project has it's functionality, and you cannot force all of them to a single class. This leads to bigger problems in the future. You may want to create multiple representations of each entity - for a list and details, each differ in number of roperties.

Comment: are you sure that this is not some issue in my entity classes or something to do with @OneToOne , but just a side impact of the serializing the movie object to json ??

Comment: The issue/problems is JPA framework.  It encourages You to create cycles in your classes, and fasterXml has no clue - it simply prints every object it can find, unless You tell him not to. This is a cost JPA framework is making on You. That is why layers should be separated (JPA and presentation-DTO). You could try to make a one directional OneToOne relation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two similar issues with your code. Both result in an infinit loop and stackoverflow.

1. JSON serialization - this can be solved by adding `@JsonIgnore` as already explained in another answer.
2. Java `toString()` method. Both entities have this method generated by `Lombok` with `@Data` annotation.

**Solution**

Add `@ToString.Exclude` annotation to the Movie field like this:

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "movieCasts")
@JsonIgnore
@ToString.Exclude
private Movie movie;
```

Answer (score 1):

What happens here is when serialising, jackson tries to serialise each reference of one side from the other side. This has caused the recursion.

You can add `@JsonIgnore` annotation to one of the entity to stop this. For your case, looks like better to add `@JsonIgnore` to the `movie` property in `MovieCast` entity. Your code will look like this.

```java
@Entity
@Data
public class MovieCast {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long castId;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "movieCasts")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Movie movie;
    private String director;
    private String producer;
    private String leadActor;
    private String leadActress;
    private String[] otherActors;
}


@Repository
public class MovieEntityRepo {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;


    public Movie findByName(String name) {
        return em.find(Movie.class, name);
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is not json , but the em.findMethod give really big stack which is consuming lot of memory , see screen shot in question please

Comment: Have you tried adding `@JsonIgnore`?

Comment: yes it just changes the json message but still the stackoveflow exception occurs