# JPA not adding ids and values to table

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Im using mcv controller and 2 page view that sends a tacoOrder object as a form and saves it using orderRepo save method. These are the classes
This is the Ingredient class:

```
@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED,force = true)
public class Ingredient {
    @Id
    private final String id;
    private final String name;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private final Type type;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "ingredient")
    private List<IngredientRef> ingredientRefs = new ArrayList<>();


    public enum Type {
        WRAP, PROTEIN, VEGGIES, CHEESE, SAUCE
    }
}
```

This is TacoOrder class:

```
@Data
@Entity
public class TacoOrder implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private Date placedAt = new Date();
    @NotBlank(message = "Delivery name is required")
    private String deliveryName;
    @NotBlank
    private String deliveryStreet;
    @NotBlank(message = "City is required")
    private String deliveryCity;
    @NotBlank(message = "State is required")
    private String deliveryState;
    @NotBlank(message = "Zip Code is required")
    private String deliveryZip;
    @CreditCardNumber(message = "Invalid Credit Card Number")
    private String ccNumber;
    @Pattern(regexp = "^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])/20(2[3-9]|[3-9][0-9])$",message = "Must be of format MM/YYYY")
    private String ccExpiration;
    @NotNull
    @Digits(integer=3, fraction=0, message="Invalid CVV")
    private String ccCVV;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "tacoOrder",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Taco> tacos = new ArrayList<>();
    public void addTaco(Taco taco) {
        this.tacos.add(taco);
    }
}
```

This is Taco class:

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Taco {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private Date createdAt = new Date();

    @NotBlank
    @Size(min = 5, message = "Name must be at least 5 characters long")
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany
    private List<Ingredient> ingredients;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "taco_order_id")
    private TacoOrder tacoOrder;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "taco", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<IngredientRef> ingredientRefs = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

This is IngredientRef class:

```
@Data
@Entity
public class IngredientRef {
    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ingredient_id")
    private Ingredient ingredient;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "taco_id")
    private Taco taco;
}
```

these are the logs

```
2023-08-31T02:30:35.257+05:30  INFO 16268 --- [io-8080-exec-10] com.example.tacohouse.OrderController    : Order submitted: TacoOrder(id=1, placedAt=Thu Aug 31 02:29:51 IST 2023, deliveryName=a, deliveryStreet=b, deliveryCity=b, deliveryState=b, deliveryZip=b, ccNumber=4417123456789113, ccExpiration=11/2024, ccCVV=111, tacos=[Taco(id=1, createdAt=Thu Aug 31 02:29:56 IST 2023, name=firstTaco, ingredients=[Ingredient(id=COTO, name=Corn Tortilla, type=WRAP, ingredientRefs=[])], tacoOrder=null, ingredientRefs=[]), Taco(id=2, createdAt=Thu Aug 31 02:30:02 IST 2023, name=secondTaco, ingredients=[Ingredient(id=CARN, name=Carnitas, type=PROTEIN, ingredientRefs=[])], tacoOrder=null, ingredientRefs=[]), Taco(id=3, createdAt=Thu Aug 31 02:30:07 IST 2023, name=thirdTaco, ingredients=[Ingredient(id=CHED, name=Cheddar, type=CHEESE, ingredientRefs=[]), Ingredient(id=JACK, name=Monterrey Jack, type=CHEESE, ingredientRefs=[])], tacoOrder=null, ingredientRefs=[])])
```

this is tables data in h2 console im using

```
ingredient table is fine
taco order table is fine
this is taco table
CREATED_AT      ID      TACO_ORDER_ID   NAME  
2023-08-31  02:29:51    1   null    firstTaco
2023-08-31  02:30:02    2   null    secondTaco
2023-08-31  02:30:07    3   null    thirdTaco
this is ingredient ref table
TACO_ID     INGREDIENT_ID  
(no rows, 0 ms)
```

Ingredient ref just shows the relation between taco and ingredients used.
Im using h-2 database and preloading ingredient table using data.sql
This is app.properties

```
spring.datasource.generate-unique-name=false
spring.datasource.name=tacocloud
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true
```

I'm seeing IDs of tacoOrder and tacos created in the database but in the tacos table which has the foreign key of tacoOrder id it's null. also ingredient_ref table is empty. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the log you posted the one you get from from the request? There are null entries in tacoOrder and empty collection in ingredientsRef. This is most probably the reason. You may set this entries in the service class before calling repo save method.

Comment: in the controller i just save the tacoOrder which the forms gives in request and then log using ToString myself. the tacoOrder oobject comes with null and after i save it , it has ids. i also made tacos related to it by annotations but its still not sending tacoOrder id to tacos

Comment: You posted Entities' code only. And they seem correct, anyway. Could you please post the code where you handle these entities? It will be very helpful to address the issue

Comment: Making the relationship with annotation is not enough. You need to set the actual relation in code. For example in you addTaco method add this code: taco.setTacoOrder(this)

Comment: yes added that, also change ingredient ref table a little bit and now tables in database are working fine but im getting a new error 
SLF4J: Failed toString() invocation on an object of type [com.example.tacohouse.Taco]
package com.example.tacohouse;
its in my controller class where im logging the taco object thats being sent through the form
```
        tacoOrder.addTaco(taco);
        log.info("Processing taco: {}", taco);
        return "redirect:/orders/current";
    }
```

Comment: This will be a recursive call of toString. Because you have a bidirectional relationship. Similar problem you will have while serializing JSON. Check my similar answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76585666/hibernate-find-by-id-for-onetoone-returns-entity-in-recursion/76586743#76586743

Comment: thanks man, i exclused tacoOrder object from toString in taco and it fixed it. only one thing that it doesnt put tacoOrder id in logs now cause i excluded it but i can just get id and put it if i want. ill be wary of json serialization too if im working with jackson in future.